# Better approach we have to follow when ever we have call the same method in different classes

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone.I am using some code for getting some data but i am confused whether it is better approach or not to use.can any body suggest me whether it is better approach or not.
I have three classes 1.BiblePlayerAppDelegate
2.BiblePlayerViewController
3.ShowProgressViewController

In BiblePlayerViewController.m:

```
-(NSString *)selectedBookTitle {

//getting the text which is in the bookSelectionButton and assign that to selectedBookTitle
selectedBookTitle = [[bookSelectionButton titleLabel]text];

//return the selectedBookTitle String
return selectedBookTitle;
}
```

I am write the above method in biblePlayerViewController.m and selectedBookTitle is class variable in biblePlayerViewController class.Here in the same class i am calling this method several times nearly 30 times i am calling this method.is it better approach for calling 30 times a method which is in that class.i am using this method in showProgressViewController also for that i am import biblePlayerViewController.h in showProgressViewController and then alloc init the biblePlayerViewController in showProgressViewController class.Is there any better approach for this.Please any body know this suggest me.It will so helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

One of the key factors of Opps is modularity and reusability  , if you plan to use a single method over different class it is good to write once and use at many locations.